Azure Storage Account StorageSharedKeyCredential
I am making a call to an internal API that returns data that I analyze, process and create a spreadsheet which i then save in a storage account, I then create a record in a reporting tool that includes the link to download the blob that was created using StorageSharedKeyCredential and an Account key. This works well until the key rotates in Azure. How can I get access to the blob without managing the access key?
Currently I have a function that Generates an SAS token for the blob like

private string GenerateSasToken(BlobClient blobClient)
{
            // Define the SAS token parameters
            BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder
            {
                BlobContainerName = blobClient.BlobContainerName,
                BlobName = blobClient.Name,
                Resource = "b" // "b" for blob, "c" for container
            };

            // Set the permissions and the expiry time for the SAS token
            sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read | BlobSasPermissions.Write);
            sasBuilder.ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(6).AddHours(1);

            // Generate the SAS token using the storage account key
            BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(blobClient.Uri);
            StorageSharedKeyCredential storageCredentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(blobUriBuilder.AccountName, this.accountKey);

            return sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(storageCredentials).ToString();
}



How can get access to the blob without managing the access key? maybe you can use BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net"), new DefaultAzureCredential());, about DefaultAzureCreneital, you can use ManagedIdentity. See this section about Azure identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#specify-a-user-assigned-managed-identity-with-defaultazurecredential

Please kindly let me know if I misunderstand your requirement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=visual-studio%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli%2Cidentity-visual-studio&pivots=blob-storage-quickstart-scratch#sign-in-and-connect-your-app-code-to-azure-using-defaultazurecredential

`using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Identity;
// TODO: Replace  with your actual storage account name
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
new Uri("https://.blob.core.windows.net"),
new DefaultAzureCredential(
new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "userManagedIdentityClientId" }//required when using user ManagedIdentity
));`

How can get access to the blob without managing the access key? You can use the User delegation key to generate sas token and access the blob refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas for that You need Storage blob delegator role.

@Dakalo Nematandani Check the below reproduced answer.


How can get access to the blob without managing the access key?

According to this MS-Document
You can be able to access the blob without using access key but the user needs RBAC role to access the storage account.
You need Storage Blob delegator or Storage Blob Data contributor role to generate the SAS token and access the blob in the Azure storage account.
Code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var containerName = "test";
        var storageAccountName = "venkat326123";
        var blobName = "scenery.jpg";
        var url = $"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net";

        // Initialize BlobServiceClient using DefaultAzureCredential
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(url), new DefaultAzureCredential());

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        // Get User Delegation Key
        var userDelegationKey = blobServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKey(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1));

        var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = containerName,
            BlobName = blobName, 
            Resource = "b", 
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
        };
        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read | BlobSasPermissions.Write);

        // Construct the Blob URI with SAS token
        var blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(containerClient.Uri)
        {
            BlobName = blobName, 
            Sas = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(userDelegationKey, blobServiceClient.AccountName)
        };

        var blobUriWithSas = blobUriBuilder.ToUri();
        Console.WriteLine(blobUriWithSas);
    }
}

Output:
https://venkat326123.blob.core.windows.net/test/scenery.jpg?skoid=63682e3exxx5d59218&sktid=9329xxxxaf6d&skt=2024-10-16T09%3A40%3A19Z&ske=2024-10-17T09%3A40%3A19Z&sks=b&skv=2024-05-04&sv=2024-05-04&st=2024-10-16T09%3A40%3A26Z&se=2024-10-17T09%3A40%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=redacted

To test, I'm using the above SAS URL to access for validation.
Browser:

Also, Refer the Tiny Wang's comment which is very helpful to authenticate with storage account.
Reference:
Create a user delegation SAS - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn
